# Get abending line number in C++ using Visual Studio

Tags: c++

Okay, I've been beating my head against a brick wall for a couple of days now...
I have a __try __except piece of code with this in it:

```
__except(ExFilter(GetExceptionCode(),GetExceptionInformation())){ 
//    Print the message ExFilter set up
          MessageBox(NULL, (LPTSTR)outline, "setup/LoadSettingsFromIni error", MB_OK);
          if(ExFilter_rc > 0) {    // should we abend?
             exit(9) ;   // yes
          }

}             // end of __except...
```

and in the ExFilter code:

```
LONG ExFilter(DWORD error,LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS lpExceptionInfo){
void *addressPtr;

    EXCEPTION_RECORD *myExecptionRecord;
    myExecptionRecord = lpExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord;
    addressPtr = myExecptionRecord->ExceptionAddress;
```

At this point, addressPtr points to:

0x00007ff73b70d4c8 {Regshot-x64-ANSI-dbg.exe!LoadSettingsFromIni(HWND__ * hDlg), Line 355}

More of the code gets the program name using "GetModuleFileName" etc.
But I already know the program name.

I've tried many ways to get the data "Line 355" but no luck.
How do I get at it so I can put it in a message?
Thanks.

Comment: Line information is not available from the `EXCEPTION_POINTERS`/`EXCEPTION_RECORD`, only the offending memory addresses. You would have to take those addresses and manually look them up in whatever debug info your compiler/linker outputs during compiling. Whether that info is even available, and whether it is embedded in the executable or stored in a external file, depends on your toolchain and configuration.

Comment: Check this out. It is possible to get what you want with the stack walking methods and the symbol APIs, etc. It isn't easy, but it is totally possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/dbghelp-functions

Comment: Thanks Remy and David... I guess the best answer is... Make sure the program doesn't abend!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure many people have found a way around this, but here is my "poor man's solution" for trapping errors I suddenly thought of the other day:
I added a counter to areas in my code that might cause a problem, and then in the __except filter added code to show the counter, which would give me a more concise area to look at.
Here is what I did:

```
char outline[1310] ;  // __except output line 
size_t rc2 ;          // lth of outline
int ctr ;


__try {
   code
   ..
   ctr = 1 ;
   code
   ..
   ctr = 2 ;
   code
   ..
   ctr = 3 ;
   code
   ..
}      // end of try


__except(ExFilter(GetExceptionCode(),GetExceptionInformation())){ 
//    Print the message ExFilter set up
          MessageBox(NULL, (LPTSTR)outline, "setup/LoadSettingsFromIni error", MB_OK);
          if(ExFilter_rc > 0) {    // should we abend?
             exit(9) ;   // yes
          }

}             // end of __except...
```

and in the ExFilter code:

```
LONG ExFilter(DWORD error,LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS 
     lpExceptionInfo){
void *addressPtr;

    EXCEPTION_RECORD *myExecptionRecord;
    myExecptionRecord = lpExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord;
    addressPtr = myExecptionRecord->ExceptionAddress;

    sprintf(outline, "");   // blank outline

    rc2 = strlen(outline);
    rc = error ;  // GetExceptionCode() passed by __except
    if (rc == EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO) {
      sprintf(outline+rc2, "Divide by Zero!");
      goto f_end7a ;       // continue
    }
     ... more code for each trapped error.....

   f_end7a: ;
      rc2 = strlen(outline);
      sprintf(outline+rc2, "\n\nError occured after instruction \"ctr = %i ;\" \n", ctr);
      return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;  // return to __except...
```

So if an error occurs, a message is displayed, with a line like:
Error occurred after instruction "ctr = 2"
and I know approximately where it happened, between ctr = 2 and ctr = 3.
This may be "Mickey Mouse", but it's better than nothing.